# GRUB Problem in Dual booting

Tags: grub2, grub-efi

When I installed Kubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows7, I was directly logged onto Kubuntu without grub, but when I install boot-repair using the terminal and run it. At one place it showed to choose the disk where should I install the grub, but I need to hit `space` button to select, instead I just entered and there was a window saying something about it and there was 2 options of `Continue without the install of grub` and I, the donkey by mistake clicked yes, then it continued as usual. When I restarted my computer, It showed option Ubuntu with one asterisk, then advance option, show setup -(this 3 options) and not windows7, please help me to install that grub. Then I again tried boot-repair, but with no result, and also tried other stuff like update-grub, os probe...etc. but with not result.

Edit 1:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GvpwfPsXsx/

Edit 2:

Image of KDE Partition:

[image]

Comment: now if you are able to log on to Kubuntu, try to install Grub-Customizer, http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/03/11/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-18-04-lts/ and it may probably show Windows7 when you boot your system.

Comment: @PRATAP, it is not visible even in grub customizer

Comment: Ok, you are now logged in Kubuntu rite, can you open terminal and do the following command? `sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`

Comment: @PRATAP, sorry it did not work.

Comment: can you attach the pic, when you open "GParted"

Comment: i have seen the KDE Partition, it seems Ok. when you open Grub-Customizer, you just saw whether it is showing Windows7 or not, Or have you tried any options there to repair the Grub?

Comment: No i have not tried any repair the grub in the customizer

Comment: try to check with the options with in the Grub-Customizer. by the way Kubuntu is installed in UEFI mode or BIOS mode?

Comment: I think so it UEFI

Comment: your windows might be in BIOS mode, can you change the boot mode in BIOS Settings and see, if windows is in BIOS mode, it will be booted to Windows. First try Options in Grub-Customizer if not succeeded then try BIOS mode changing option.

Comment: Would u help me with the script code for windows, then it is done.

Comment: have you changed the boot mode and seen? if you go through your Edit 1: line numbers 760 to 772 the Update-Grub is not showing your windows7. Line num 775 says The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Comment: Please suggest me a good way I did not understand anything. Please write your answer.

Comment: Your Partitioning is not good. You may need to repartion and then install again. Take the backup first. I will write my answer in few minutes as I am at work.

Comment: Please notice that when I first install Kubuntu it showed a bug, of  efi related so I got the solution from askubuntu to install in that manner.

Comment: can you go through the http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GvpwfPsXsx/ line number 775 which shows about your partitioning.

Comment: You have Windows installed in BIOS boot mode with MBR partitioning. But you originally installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode which normally uses gpt partitioning. And then it looks like you re-installed grub in BIOS boot mode as you have grub in MBR, but still have mount of ESP - efi system partition in fstab.  ReBoot Ubuntu live installer in BIOS boot mode, add Boot-Repair and in Advanced options run the full uninstall of grub (the UEFI version) and re-install of grub-pc (BIOS) version. Since newer UEFI based hardware original mistake was installing Windows in BIOS boot mode. But difficult to change.

Comment: @oldfred, Please elaborate your answer in a good manner and post in the answer section.Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I can understand, but in the link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition , it says in first 100GB and to use windows tool to resize, help me on that part.